# Sent out broken link in a Mailchimp campaign - how to do a bulk redirect?

Tags: django, redirect, mailchimp, mezzanine

Just joined but have been a lurker for a while and found this community very helpful.

I've just sent out an email newsletter via Mailchimp to our 15,000 subscribers and included the wrong link (it should have been .../grandchallenges not .../grand-challenges. I've done a simple redirect on our website, but Mailchimp inserts individual URLs, so folks end up with a link that looks like this: .../grand-challenges/?mc_cid=debb7846d7&mc_eid=18de3e5c2a. As such i'd have to do 15,000 individual redirect requests, unless there's a way to 'bulk' redirect everything after the slash.

Btw - we're using Mezzanine as a Django CMS not Wordpress: http://mezzanine.jupo.org, so the answer won't be a WP plug-in.

Thanks!

Comment: what server are you using? Apache or nginx? In both cases you can add redirect rules for specific paths, not changing the remainder of the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^grand-challenges\/(.*)$   http://example.com/grandchallenges/$1
```

you can check it here: [htacces Tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a5a6e11a-ca2f-5b0e-bcac-284eb1a2cf27)

Answer (score 0):

The .htacess file on the server can redirect anything. Add the line:

Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html

See this post from hosting company, media temple for an example. Your hosting company should have specific instructions.

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file

Accessing htacess can be done via FTP. I recommend FileZilla which is free and open source. https://filezilla-project.org/

See this article for additional info on htacess.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is here. Django doesn't take the querystring into account when you set up URLs, so your redirect view will work for everyone. All you then need to do is to pass on whatever query arguments you received.

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def redirect_everyone(request):
    return redirect('/grandchallenges?' + urlencode(request.GET))
```